# Data passing from UITextField to HTML and Vice Versa in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Send string Hi from UITextField to local HTML and display it in HTML then from HTML send hello and should be updated in UILabel using WKScriptMessageHandler

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code

GetValue.js -

```js
var returnedValue = "";

function display(val){
    var value = true;
    try {
        webkit.messageHandlers.reciever.postMessage(value);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('error');
    }
    returnedValue = val;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = returnedValue;
}
```

PostValue.js

```js
function myFunction() {
var value = document.getElementById("name").value;
    try {
  webkit.messageHandlers.scriptHandler.postMessage(value);
        } catch(err) {
    console.log('error');
    }
}
```

WebPage.html -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.5">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="postValue.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="getValue.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
        Enter Value <input id="name" type="text"/><br><br>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

ViewController -

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler,UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var webValueLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

@IBOutlet weak var toWebTextField: UITextField!
var bool: Bool = true
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    toWebTextField.delegate = self
    let URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "webPage", withExtension: "html")
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: URL!)
    webView.load(requestObj as URLRequest)

    webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self,name: "scriptHandler")
    webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "reciever")

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if (bool){
        let hello = toWebTextField.text!
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("display('\(hello)')",
            completionHandler: nil)
    }
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if(message.name == "scriptHandler") {
        print("JavaScript is sending a message \(message.body)")
        webValueLabel.text = message.body as? String

    }
    if(message.name == "reciever") {
        bool = message.body as! Bool

    }

}
}
extension ViewController {
override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
}
```